# Can I be arrested if I'm not home and there are drugs in my room?

Tags: criminal-law

If I am out somewhere, and say my door is open and there are drugs in plain view, if a cop was in the house could I be arrested even though I'm not there?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, there is a co-occupant consent rule (United States v. Matlock, 415 U.S. 164 (1974)). If a co-occupant of your house consented to a search, anything in plain view from the common areas is useable as justification for probable cause (for arrest) and admissible as evidence at trial.

Comment: "Common areas" implies *not* a co-occupant's room, right? Unless you sleep on the couch.

Comment: the answer says "visible from a common area" and the question said "door open".